error creating bundle with ./gradlew bundleRelease
I am not a developer. I did this for fun, but I haven't touched code for several years now, and I've forgotten all about the principles. so please, keep it simple, and tell me what to do precisely
I created an unpretentious application, which we use as a family, and which I put on the play store for a practical purpose, and in case it might interest someone.
Today, I have to update API level from 33 to 34 (asked by google).
I'm used to create apk with ./gradlew assembleRelease and the bundle with ./gradlew bundleRelease
All seems to work normally for the apk, but error for the bundle:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
75 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 73 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/ssd/chris/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp/app/build.gradle' line: 183

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:bundleRelease'.
> Could not create task ':app:bundleDemoRelease'.
   > DefaultTaskContainer#register(String, Action) on task set cannot be executed in the current context.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 484ms

Do I need to change somthing in build or the method to create bundle please?
app/build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdk 34

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            // Optional, specify signing versions used
            v1SigningEnabled true
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 260
        versionName '2.6.0'
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "VARIANT", "\"dev\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEV", "true"
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "VARIANT", "\"\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEV", "false"
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                def appName
                //Check if an applicationName property is supplied; if not use the name of the parent project.
                if (project.hasProperty("applicationName")) {
                    appName = applicationName
                } else {
                    appName = parent.name
                }
                variant.outputs.all { output ->
                    outputFileName = "${appName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            applicationId "fr.myappdemo"
            versionNameSuffix '-demo'
        }
        full {
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += ['META-INF/LICENSE.md', 'META-INF/NOTICE.md']
        }
    }
    namespace 'fr.myapp'
    flavorDimensions += 'app'
}

dependencies {
    modules {
        module("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7") {
            replacedBy("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib", "kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        module("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8") {
            replacedBy("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib", "kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.1'
    implementation 'org.droidparts:droidparts-misc:3.2.5'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.12.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.7'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.7'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0'
}
allprojects {
   repositories {
      maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   }
}
configurations {
    configureEach {
        exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module: 'lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx'
    }
}

static String firstMatchingSubstring(String taskName, String[] keys) {
    def lcName = taskName.toLowerCase()
    for(String key: keys) { if(lcName.contains(key.toLowerCase())) return key }
    return null
}

/**
 *
 * @param taskName e.g., bundleMyFlavorRelease or bundleRelease
 * @return
 */
String getBuildType(String taskName) {
    return firstMatchingSubstring(taskName, getBuildTypeNames())
}

/**
 *
 * @param taskName e.g., bundleMyFlavorRelease
 * @return
 */
String getFlavor(String taskName) {
    return firstMatchingSubstring(taskName, getProductFlavorNames())
}

String[] getBuildTypeNames() {
    def types = []
    android.buildTypes.configureEach { type -> types.add(type.name) }
    return types
}

String[] getProductFlavorNames() {
    def flavors = []
    android.productFlavors.configureEach { flavor -> flavors.add(flavor.name) }
    return flavors
}

tasks.configureEach { task ->
    def name = task.name
    //Skip some unnecessary tasks
    if (name.startsWith("bundle")
            && !name.contains("Classes")
            && !name.contains("Resources")
            && name != "bundle") {

        def renameTaskName = "rename${task.name.capitalize()}Aab"
        def version = "${android.defaultConfig.versionName}"
        def flavor = getFlavor(name)
        def type = getBuildType(name)
        if(flavor == null || type == null) return

        def outputName
        if (flavor == "full")
            outputName = "MyApp-$version"
        else
            outputName = "MyApp-$version-$flavor"

        tasks.register(renameTaskName) {
            def path = "${rootDir}/app/${flavor}/${type}/"
            def originalFile = "$path/app-${flavor}-${type}.aab"

            doLast {
                if (file("$originalFile").exists()) {
                    ant.move file: "$originalFile",
                            tofile: "$path/${outputName}.aab"
                }
            }
        }
        task.finalizedBy(renameTaskName)
    }
}


Change the gradle script to use project.afterEvaluate to ensure that the tasks are registered after the project is evaluated.

@Bob I don't know at all what that means.

Try modifying the code to use project.afterEvaluate to ensure that the tasks are registered after the project is evaluated. like this project.afterEvaluate {                 android.applicationVariants.all { variant -> and here also tasks.configureEach { task ->     def name = task.name     //Skip some unnecessary tasks

Try
./gradlew bundleDemoRelease //for Demo

./gradlew bundleFullRelease /*for Full. Looking at the code it appears you might need to configure it further */

We need to specify Product Flavor name in the command while creating a bundle or apk

Same error for each. And I don't have to specify Produc Flavor name for apk. ./gradlew assembleRelease is sufficient.
